# Sandbox refresh regressed version

Tags: sandbox-refresh, release

Our Sandbox was upgraded to Spring 2016 release in Jan 2016.Our production was still on Winter 2016.We refreshed our sandbox , which took our sandbox to winter 2016 as our prod was still on winter 2016.Is there any way other than contacting Salesforce support to get our sandboxes on to spring 2016?

Thanks

Arvind

Answer (score 3):

The only alternative is to wait. In the future, make sure you read the "Salesforce Sandbox Preview Instructions" for a particular release (which is emailed to administrators in advance). Some sandboxes *must* be refreshed during the preview window to get the next release, and other sandboxes *must not* be refreshed during the preview window to get the next release. If you don't pay attention to these schedules, then you'll have to deal with having the wrong version until the final upgrade schedule. Support may be able to fix this for you, but there's definitely no way you can fix it yourself if you don't pay attention to the opt-in/opt-out periods.